# how to use if else statement for click event to check the input value is true or false

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-click-event

```
function event() {
   $('main').css("display", "none");
   $('section').css("display", "block");
}

function startButton(){
   if($('input').val() === true){
   $('button').on('click', event)
   } else if($('input').val() === false){
      $('button').off('click', event)
   }
}
startButton()
```

when I do if statement with `if($('input').val() === "")`
the click event works whether the user typed text in input or not
when I check the Boolean on console it returns true or false depending on the input value is filled or not

I would like to add click event on the button when the user types in the input and remove the click event when there is no text written in the input

can someone help me with my code?

Comment: `.val()` always returns a string, not a boolean. Why are you comparing with `true` and `false`?

Comment: If the user clicks the start button multiple times, you'll add the event handler many times.

Comment: Why don't you try disabling the button.

Comment: tried if($('input').val() === "") and it adds the click event whether there is the value or not.. so tried with boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to the other from [object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5222459/object-reference).

But the event handler won't be registered many times.

```
// The function to execute on button click
function event(){
  $('main').css("display", "none");
  $('section').css("display", "block");
});

// The input check
$('input').on("input",function(){
  if(($this).val()!=""){
    $('button').off('click', event).on('click', event); // Off then on to prevent the handler to be registered multiple times.
  }else{
    $('button').off('click', event);
  }
});
```

Alternatively... And this is probably the best way to do it:

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
  $('main').css("display", "none");
  $('section').css("display", "block");
});

$('input').on("input",function(){
  if(($this).val()!=""){
    $('button').prop("disabled",false);
  }else{
    $('button').prop("disabled",true);
  }
});
```

Add the "disabled" attribute in your button markup for the onload state:

```
<button disabled>whatever</button>
```

Comment: the first one works!
can you please explain what the "input" in the first line is?

Comment: input is an event too. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: About the selector... I suggest you use an `id` or a `class`... Like `#userText` or something... The same idea about the button. Because, as is, is will apply on every input and buttons on the page.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the green check mark aside the voting system if that works for you ;)

Comment: I improved the"alternative"... Which I recommand, in fact. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, your scenario is when the input has a value, the button click event will be on, then if there are no value on input, button click event will be off? If I'm right, then this should be the answer.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if($('input').val() != "")
        $('button').on('click', event)
    else
        $('button').off('click', event)
});
```

Comment: yes that's correct, i tried with your code and still not working and catching the error saying Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5009)